# Angular2 - Variable variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Short version:**

How to use [$$a](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like in PHP but in angular2?

**Long version:**

I have 2 `const` variables `const foo = 'string'` and `const bar = 'string2'`

And 1 variable `foo2 = 'foo'`

Would it be possible to call something like `this.{{foo2}}` with a result of `'string'`?

I know it's possible in PHP with [$$a](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use brackets notation:

```
{{ this[foo2] }}
```

[**Example**](https://ng-run.com/edit/V7QaAmtYQb5fNrOG8I4f)